# Most reliable/effective finger locks?

Tags: aikido, jujutsu, pankration

Jujutsu, Chin-na, and Aikido all have excellent finger locks.  Which are the most effective?

- What are most reliable finger locks?

Also interested in [pinky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_finger) locks specifically b/c that's the weakest finger.

Note that finger locking in martial arts is very ancient:

> Beside Sostratus is a statue of Leontiscus, a man wrestler, a native of Sicily from Messene on the Strait. He was crowned, they say, by the Amphictyons and twice by the Eleans, and his mode of wrestling was similar to the pancratium of Sostratus the Sicyonian. For they say that Leontiscus did not know how to throw his opponents, but won by bending their fingers.
>
> <sub>Source: [Pausanias, *Description of Greece*, 6.4.3](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0160%3Abook%3D6%3Achapter%3D4%3Asection%3D3)</sub>

Comment: Effective for what?

Comment: In order to answer that question finger locks would first have to be legal to use in sparring. I don't know of any legitimate venues that allow them. Finger locks come on too fast to tap out in time so you'd just wind up with all your fighters nursing broken fingers.

Comment: @JujutsuAddict388 Asking from the standpoint of self-defense/combat as opposed to sparring or sport fighting.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann Effective for controlling an opponent's body, potentially submitting them, or simply breaking the fingers to diminish their capacity, and potentially end combat.  (I've been put into wicked finger locks by chin-na experts who don't telegraph the move, or even distract you before grabbing the digits.)